# conditions tree and backtrace

Tags: python

I have some graphs and I generates code from them. One condition from one node. For example generated code can look like this one:

```
def function():
    steps = []

    if True:
        steps.append(1)

        if True:
            steps.append(2)

            if False:
                steps.append(3)
                return 'a', steps

            if False:
                steps.append(4)
                return 'b', steps


        if True:
            steps.append(5)

            if True:
                steps.append(6)

                if False:
                    steps.append(7)
                    return 'a', steps
            if True:
                steps.append(8)
                return 'b', steps
```

I replaced real conditions with `True`/`False` to make example cleaner.

This function return tuple `('b', [1, 2, 5, 6, 8])`, so some value and steps which was taken. I want modify this code to remove steps which was not successful. So after modification function should return `('b', [1, 5, 8])`.

My question is, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this, would be to `pop` after every failed group.

```
def function():
    steps = []

    if True:
        steps.append(1)

        if True:
            steps.append(2)

            if False:
                steps.append(3)
                return 'a', steps

            if False:
                steps.append(4)
                return 'b', steps

            steps.pop() #removes 2 from steps

        if True:
            steps.append(5)

            if True:
                steps.append(6)

                if False:
                    steps.append(7)
                    return 'a', steps

            steps.pop() #remove the 6

            if True:
                steps.append(8)
                return 'b', steps

        steps.pop() #remove the 5
    steps.pop() # removes the 1
```

Comment: But using `elif` instead of `if` is not the same. Some conditions will be not checked... I don't think that it will work with my example.

Comment: Could you show me it on my example? I'm not sure how you want to change code with steps 6, 7 and 8.

Comment: @Adam updated, looks neater without the else :), hope this is what you want.